# How to modify an atributte of one element of a list

Tags: javascript, list

I have a list of animals and I need to change a boolean property of just one animal when I click in the bottom indicatated, I have tried the code bellow, but it changes all animals of the list and when I click in the buttom again it does not change to another value(false), it just change once and I need to change the value everytime I click in the buttom. All animals in the list have an Id. Could you help me please?

```
public UpdateStatus(){

  if(this.pets.filter(pet=> pet.Favorito==true)){
    this.pets.filter(pet=> pet.Favorito==false);
  }else if(this.pets.filter(pet=> pet.Favorito==false)){
    this.pets.filter(pet=>pet.Favorito==true);
  }
}
```

```
<ion-button (click)="UpdateStatus()">

    <ion-icon slot="end" name="heart"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```

Here is an example of an animal in the list and the buttom, in the end there is the property I want to change

[image: Here is an example of an animal in the list and the buttom, in the end there is the property I want to change]

Comment: How that one specific animal is determined?

Comment: That `if()` will always be truthy since filter() returns an array and `if([])` is always truthy even if there are no matches. You want `find()` probably if you are looking for a specific instance

Comment: Your code doesn't change anything. `==` is for comparison, `=` is for assigning.

Comment: Hello @Areg, every animal has your own id, that's what I'm using.

Comment: @AriadneAndrade ok check the updated answer see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass id of that specific pet to UpdateStatus as a parameter

```
public UpdateStatus(id){
 const index = this.pets.map(i => i.id).indexOf(id);
 this.pets[index].Favorito = !this.pets[index].Favorito;
}
```